# Fell down [in/on] the runway

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct: The fashion model fell down **in** the runway, or **on** the runway?

Answer (score 1):

"On" is the right preposition for things happening in relation to the surface of stages, platforms, tables, floors, and the like. A runway is an elevated platform, basically a stage that extends into an audience area. The model was "on" the runway. This runway might might have been *in* a theater, auditorium, tent, or studio, but she was *on* the runway.

Note that things can also happen *by, at, before, across, above, below* (and more) with respect to a stage or table. But in regard to placement in contact with a surface, "on" is pretty much always right.